# Rendering a cubemap in GLES20

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I have a bitmap for a 6x1 cubemap obtained from a URI, which needs to be rendered using the renderer.

How do I upload the cubemap faces to the GPU? What would be the set of GLES20 calls I need to make in surfaceCreated()?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Cube and Plane classes](https://gist.github.com/marktani/532bfc8deb38fed021bf) I prepared for my [most recent article](https://medium.com/@nilan/introduction-to-the-google-cardboard-sdk-19d2c771202c).

For those classes it would be the best if you actually convert your texture into 6 textures, one for every face of the cube.

The "easiest" way to add textures is to pass them in the constructor as bitmaps. If you want to create the Cube first, then load textures afterwards you will have to deal with thread-safety and you'll have to make sure that the texture update is recognized in the onDraw method of your planes.